# Python set to postgres array using psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

We use Python sets extensively and need to insert data from sets into our Postgres DB, which  doesn't have a similar data type. We'd like to insert all sets into the DB as arrays. We could do that by wrapping all sets with `list()`, but it would be nice to write a simple psycopg2 adaptor instead. I've looked at [the docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-types), but it's unclear how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by registering an adapter for the `set` type and use the `adapt` function to treat the set as a list. This'll give the set the necessary `getquoted()` function from the list, which'll turn it into `ARRAY[x,y,...]` in the SQL string. See the code below.

```
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, adapt
def adapt_set(my_set):
    return adapt(list(my_set))
register_adapter(set, adapt_set)
```

Comment: Figured out the solution after drafting the question so tried the Q&A style answer. Hope it's helpful to anyone!